# Dynamics 365 pass ExecutionContext or FormContext from RibbonWorkbench on Associated View in a supported way

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Setup:
Dynamics v9 on-premise - however, it needs to work on Dynamics 365 Online as well.
I am working on an Associated View of an Entity that is on the Account Form.
To get to this view, I click the associated view button on a SubGrid that is on the Account Form.

I am passing the PrimaryControl into my JavaScript function.

The goal is to get the Account Name and the Account Id.

Below is what I found that does and does not work:

```
function myFunction(primaryControl) {

    var formContext = primaryControl;  // This is not the formContext in this scenario.

    formContext = primaryControl.getFormContext();  // undefined error

    console.log(primaryControl.constructor.getName());  // This = "Mscrm.FormProxyForRibbon"

    // The following works correctly, but is it supported?
    formContext = primaryControl.get_crmFormControl().getFormContext();
    var accountId = formContext.data.entity.getId().replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
    var accountName = formContext.data.entity.getPrimaryAttributeValue();
}
```

The get_crmFormControl() works correctly, but will it work in CRM online?
Is there some supported way to do this, as I could not find any of this documented anywhere?

This is what the primaryControl looks like in Console:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**using this code.**

```js
function GetAccountIdAndName(primaryControl) {
    var formContext = primaryControl.getFormContext();
  
    if (formContext && formContext.data && formContext.data.entity.getEntityName() === "account") {

      var accountId = formContext.data.entity.getId();
      var accountName = formContext.data.entity.getPrimaryAttributeValue();
  
      // Use accountId and accountName as needed
      console.log("AccountId: " + accountId);
      console.log("AccountName: " + accountName);
    } else {
      console.log("This function should be executed on an account record only.");
    }
  }


//**or using Xrm.WebApi**

function GetAccountIdAndNameFromUrlId() {
    var recordId = Xrm.Page.context.getQueryStringParameters().id.replace(/[{}]/g, "").toLowerCase();
    var entityName = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName();
  
    var query = entityName + "(" + recordId + ")?$select=accountid,name";
  
    Xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord(entityName, recordId, query)
      .then(function (result) {
        var accountId = result.accountid;
        var accountName = result.name;
        
        // Use accountId and accountName as needed
        console.log("AccountId: " + accountId);
        console.log("AccountName: " + accountName);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error occurred: " + error.message);
      });
  }
```

function GetAccountIdAndName(primaryControl) {
var formContext = primaryControl.getFormContext();

```
if (formContext && formContext.data && formContext.data.entity.getEntityName() === "account") {

  var accountId = formContext.data.entity.getId();
  var accountName = formContext.data.entity.getPrimaryAttributeValue();

  // Use accountId and accountName as needed
  console.log("AccountId: " + accountId);
  console.log("AccountName: " + accountName);
} else {
  console.log("This function should be executed on an account record only.");
}
```

}
function GetAccountIdAndNameFromUrlId() {
var recordId = Xrm.Page.context.getQueryStringParameters().id.replace(/[{}]/g, "").toLowerCase();
var entityName = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName();

```
var query = entityName + "(" + recordId + ")?$select=accountid,name";

Xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord(entityName, recordId, query)
  .then(function (result) {
    var accountId = result.accountid;
    var accountName = result.name;
    
    // Use accountId and accountName as needed
    console.log("AccountId: " + accountId);
    console.log("AccountName: " + accountName);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error occurred: " + error.message);
  });
```

}

Comment: As stated in the question primaryControl.getFormContext() does not work for Mscrm.FormProxyForRibbon.